# How do determine if a Swift value is an Array?

Tags: swift, generics

In Swift, how do I check if an arbitrary value, of static type `Any`, is an Array over any sort of type whatsoever?

As can be seen from running the snippet below, the obvious approach of checking if the value is `Array<Any>` does not work:

```
func isArray(v:Any) -> Bool
{
    if v is Array<Any> {
        return true
    }
    return false
 }

 let intArray:[Int] = [1,2,3]
 let anyArray:[Any] = [1,2,3]

 isArray(intArray) // => false
 isArray(anyArray) // => true
```